# c# - Setting login textbox property to invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I have a program with a login interface. User can choose to login either by windows authentication mode or by SQL server authentication mode by choosing the radio button. Here is a snapshot of the interface:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWKQO.png
```

When user selects windows auth, the user does not need to enter any credentials on the username and password textbox. If user selects SQL server auth, user have to fill up the credentials on the textboxes. So, I would like to set the textboxes for windows auth to blank or invisible so user will not be allowed to enter credentials into it if they try to.

Below is the code:

```
private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool useWindowsAuth = WindowsAuth.Checked; // Check radio button for windows authentication

            string userName = string.Empty;
            string password = string.Empty;

            // Windows authentication mode : if textbox are empty , display message
            if (!useWindowsAuth)
            {
                userName = textBox1.Text;
                password = textBox2.Text;

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please provide Username and Password");
                    return;
                }
            }

            //create sql connection to both authentication mode
            var connStrBldr = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connStrBldr.DataSource = "XXXXXXXXXX";
            connStrBldr.InitialCatalog = "Test";

            if (useWindowsAuth)
            {
                connStrBldr.IntegratedSecurity = true;  // accepts user login without any credentials
            }
            else
            {
                connStrBldr.IntegratedSecurity = false;  // accepts user login with credential stored in sql server
                connStrBldr.UserID = userName;
                connStrBldr.Password = password;
            }

            bool validUser = true;

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStrBldr.ToString()))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    //lookup on login credentials in sql server
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException) // An exception will be caught if invalid credentials were used.
            {
                validUser = false;
            }

            //validate if user is successful or failed
            if (validUser)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login successful!");
                this.Hide();
                MainPage main = new MainPage();
                main.Show();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login failed!");
            }
        }
```

What property would I need to implement this?

Comment: Do it on the client side with some Javascript.

Comment: since it's a form. Give the radiobuttons a Value changed event. Then see which one is checked using an if statement. and use `GUIElement.Visibility = false` to hide the elements you want to hide

Comment: You are looking for [TextBox ReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-create-a-read-only-text-box-windows-forms) property

Comment: Is there a difference with TextBox Enabled?

Comment: In read only mode you can't edit content but you can focus and select text. In your case probably use of Enable property would be better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you looking for?

```
 textBox1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: I want something like it prevents user entering credentials to the textboxes, maybe the textboxes could be dim in color to let users know they can't enter or when users try to click on textbox, it won't allow

Comment: Give the radio buttons an event. Use `textbox.Visibilty = false` to make them invisible or use `Textbox.Disable = true` to make them greyed out and prevent the user from interacting.

Comment: I used this : textBox1.Visible = false;   and it the textbox just dissapears

Comment: I want it grey out or maybe user's can't write on it so it looks better.

Comment: @DragOnvil I don't think there is such property in visual studio for textbox.disable . There is only Textbox.Enable

Comment: `Textob.Enable = false` I'm sorry. My bad then, haven't used that in ages thought it was the other way around. ah sarah also edited the Answer already.